# What will printf do when not enough arguments are passed?

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior, format-specifiers

Let's say I used `printf` without passing enough arguments to match the format specifiers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("missing argument: %s\n");
}
```

Are there any guarantees on what the result will be?
On my machine, nothing gets printed at all.
Is this always the case, or is there a potential for it to print the string with an resolved specifier?

for example:
`missing argument: %s`

or:
`missing argument:`

Comment: The behavior will be undefined.

Comment: It is UB so there is no standard as to what it will do.

Comment: Compiler could issue a warning, but generally speaking, the format string is not known at the compile time. Consider `printf(s, 1, 2);`

Comment: Apparently you are not the first in the cycle.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660232/printf-insufficient-arguments

Comment: @EugeneSh. why not CV as dup then?

Comment: @Olaf I am generally trying not to CV questions with accepted answers as a courtesy for the answerers...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: That attracts bad questions and supports duplicates, thus lowers overal quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C spec is explicit on this point:

> ... If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined.  ...
>    C11dr §7.21.6.1 2

Are there any guarantees on what the result will be?  --> No.

(On my machine, nothing gets printed at all.) Is this always the case --> No.

Is there a potential for it to print the string with an resolved specifier? --> Yes. The behavior is undefined. anything may happen.

Answer (score 1):

[printf reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) states that passing less arguments than specified in the format yields undefined behaviour:

> - arguments specifying data to print. If any argument is not the type expected by the corresponding conversion specifier, or if there are
>     fewer arguments than required by format, the behavior is undefined. If
>     there are more arguments than required by format, the extraneous
>     arguments are evaluated and ignored