# "Dead Value" when there's no parameters in va_list

Tags: c, string, format

I'm learning C and I have a doubt about something.

When I use a format "%s" and there's no other value in the list of parameters, in that space a new string is generated. I called it "dead value", and everytime that I execute the program it always returns a different value starting with a letter G.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int age = 3;

    printf("%d, %s", age);
    return 0;
}
```

[Outputs of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kilj.png)

When I changed the format to %d, the "dead value" generates a large negative number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int age = 3;

    printf("%d, %d", age);
    return 0;
}
```

[Outputs of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9bPB.png)

Comment: The `printf("%d, %s", age);` and `printf("%d, %d", age);` are both *undefined behaviour*. It's not what happens that is relevant, but getting the code right. C has no concept of a sensible "default value" to output in your codes.

Comment: Please see [printf insufficient arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660232/printf-insufficient-arguments). The compiler should issue warnings about it, and at runtime the `printf()` believes what the format string is telling it: that there are well defined values presented to it, but they don't exist. The function might do anything crazy, especially with the unsatisfied `%s` format, which may result in trying to access memory illegally.

Comment: Thank u! 
Now I understand it better.

Comment: Welcome! Hint for next time – please try to avoid posting images when you can copy/paste *text* into the question.